# extend list in python until condition is met

Tags: python, list

I would like to create a list when `row[4]` is digit, then extend it with `row` whenever `row[4]` is not a digit but I am getting duplicate results. Can someone guide me in the right direction?

this is a sample csv file:

```
Name,Last,,,Account
joe,joe last,,,11111
joe address,city,state,zip,
,,,,
sam,sam last,,,22222
sam address,city,state,zip,
,,,,
bob,bob last,,,33333
bob address,city,state,zip,
```

my code:

```
localdir = 'C:\\Users\\User\\My Documents'
fn = 'test_file.csv'

with open(os.path.join(localdir, fn), 'rb') as fopen:
    csvdata = list(csv.reader(fopen))

data = []
for row in csvdata:
    if not row[0] or row[0].startswith('Name'):
        continue
    if row[4].isdigit():
        accts = []
    accts += row
    data.append(accts)

for line in data:
    print(line)
```

My results are:

```
['joe', 'joe last', '', '', '11111', 'joe address', 'city', 'state', 'zip', '']
['joe', 'joe last', '', '', '11111', 'joe address', 'city', 'state', 'zip', '']
['sam', 'sam last', '', '', '22222', 'sam address', 'city', 'state', 'zip', '']
['sam', 'sam last', '', '', '22222', 'sam address', 'city', 'state', 'zip', '']
['bob', 'bob last', '', '', '33333', 'bob address', 'city', 'state', 'zip', '']
['bob', 'bob last', '', '', '33333', 'bob address', 'city', 'state', 'zip', '']
```

I would like to get:

```
['joe', 'joe last', '', '', '11111', 'joe address', 'city', 'state', 'zip', '']
['sam', 'sam last', '', '', '22222', 'sam address', 'city', 'state', 'zip', '']
['bob', 'bob last', '', '', '33333', 'bob address', 'city', 'state', 'zip', '']
```

Comment: Are there newlines in the actual file breaking up those rows or is that only how it being displayed here? I.e. is `joe address` actually on a new line after `11111`?

Comment: With the exact same code I'm getting errors in both Python 2 and 3. Also, after fixing the obvious errors (opening the file in `r` instead of `rb` mode; setting an initial value for `accts`) I don't get the same output as you. Please provide a proper minimal working example.

Comment: Are all the ids unique and grouped?

Comment: yes all id's (account numbers) are unique.

Comment: And all data is grouped? i.e every  two lines then an empty row?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham yes, the only exception is the header, so its header, line1, line 2, line 3, line 1, etc...

Comment: @jes516, then it is much simpler, you don't need to check anything just pull the lines in threes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is that you're appending `accnts` for each line in the file.

Change your if (the last 4 lines of your loop) to this:

```
if row[4].isdigit():
    accts = []
else:
    data.append(accts)

accts += row
```

Or you can rewrite the logic to be more understandable..

```
with open(os.path.join(localdir, fn), 'rb') as fopen:
    data = []
    reader = csv.reader(fopen)
    header = next(reader)
    for row in reader:
             next_row = next(reader)
             blank_row = next(reader)
             data.append(row + next_row)
```

(This only works if you are sure that your format is consistent)

Comment: Not my dv but your code would not run in python3 and you can do this quite easily without a the while loop and try

Comment: @PadraicCunningham no where does it say it has to run in python3 (except for that `print(x)`), so that argument is invalid, but yes, the while is not ideal

Comment: @ChadS. Thank you sir, re-doing the `if` worked perfect.

Comment: fixed for 2-3 compatibility.

Comment: @taesu, it is tagged python so we cannot assume  either is python2 or 3, using `next(reader)` would also work for both so there is no real reason not to use it

Comment: That last edit still doesn't work. By always reading 2 lines in row, you tend to miss the important stuff in a file that has 1 header and then alternates at 3 lines.

Comment: Yeah I submitted a second too early

Comment: @ChadS.You can continue to extend row until you assign row to another empty list? I did not know you can do that. I was going through the `else` and it didn't make sense until i realized you can extend row up until you re-assign row to an empty list (another memory location). Thank you

Answer (score 2):

You just need to skip the header, get three rows at a time, pulling the first two:

```
from itertools import islice
import csv

with open("out.csv") as f:
    next(f)
    r = csv.reader(f)
    out = [row[0] + row[1] for row in iter(lambda: list(islice(r, 3)), [])]
```

Output:

```
[['joe', 'joe last', '', '', '11111', 'joe address', 'city', 'state', 'zip', ''], 
['sam', 'sam last', '', '', '22222', 'sam address', 'city', 'state', 'zip', ''], 
['bob', 'bob last', '', '', '33333', 'bob address', 'city', 'state', 'zip', '']]
```

Using `python3` we can unpack without error:

```
from itertools import islice
import csv

with open("out.csv") as f:
    next(f)
    r = csv.reader(f)
    print([a + b for a, b, *_ in iter(lambda: list(islice(r, 3)), [])])
```

Answer (score 1):

This isn't a standard csv file because alternating rows have different meanings. Fortunately, since `csv.reader` is an iterator, its easy to grab the next row when needed using `next()`.

```
import csv

# todo: debug test file
open('test_file.csv', 'w').write("""       Name,    Lastname,        ,     ,    Account
        joe,    joe last,        ,     ,      11111
 joe address,       city,   state,  zip,
            ,           ,        ,     ,
         sam,   sam last,        ,     ,      22222
 sam address,       city,   state,  zip,
            ,           ,        ,     ,
         bob,   bob last,        ,     ,      33333
 bob address,       city,   state,  zip,
            ,           ,        ,     ,
""")

with open('test_file.csv') as fp:
    reader = csv.reader(fp)
    for row in reader:
        row = [c.strip() for c in row]
        # skip empty lines and rows w/o col 0, then check digit
        if row and row[0] and row[4].isdigit():
            # add next line
            row.extend(c.strip() for c in next(reader))
            print(row)
```